# Google Analytics not tracking directories correctly

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I have an issue with setting up Google Analytics for a domain with several directories. Here is what I have:

```
www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com/site-one/
www.mydomain.com/site-two/
www.mydomain.com/site-three/
www.mydomain.com/site-four/
www.mydomain.com/site-five/
```

Each of these directories are effectively separate websites, but they all come under mydomain.com. My issue is that I've set them up so that mydomain.com is the main account, with site-one, site-two, site-three etc each being a property under that account.

For each of the properties, I have the relevant url. For example:

For the mydomain.com/site-one/ Default URL I have set it to http://www.mydomain.com/site-one/

What I've noticed is that since doing this, I only seem to be getting visits tracked on mydomain.com, but none of the sub-domain properties.

I'm sure there is probably something I'm not doing right...so if anyone can help I would really appreciated it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure what you exactly want to achieve, you want them all in one report or in different reports? anyway i think this is what you want.

Edit the profile number for each site.

```
www.mydomain.com UA-12345678-1
www.mydomain.com/site-one/ UA-12345678-2
www.mydomain.com/site-two/ UA-12345678-3
www.mydomain.com/site-three/ UA-12345678-4
www.mydomain.com/site-four/ UA-12345678-5
www.mydomain.com/site-five/ UA-12345678-6
```

Comment: Ah I see, looks like I have the tracking code the same for all directories, so it's just tracking mydomain.com and not treating each directory as it's own profile. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ad `_setCookiePath()` to your GA call within `<head>`.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#singleSubDirectory